# Como actualizo los nombres de los archivos de mi tarjeta sd luego de cambiarle el nombre a uno, ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android-studio

pasa que cojo un archivo y luego lo guardo en la misma ubicación pero con otro nombre, pero me toca esperar un rato a que android me reconozca el cambio o reiniciar el celular, estoy programando en java con Android studio, agradeceria sus respuestas

Comment: " lo guardo en la misma ubicación pero con otro nombre pero me toca esperar un rato a que android me reconozca el cambio" ¿El cambio es que no te lo guarda?  y de repente aparece en esa ubicación ?

Comment: el cambio esque le cambio el nombre al archivo y me toca ir a e administrador de archivos y darle actualizar para que lo reconozca o reinicar el celular, quiero hacerlo directamente